# By inserting a new button and registering a product, old products break! Angular 8 + MongoDB

Tags: html, angular, mongodb, nosql

I created two buttons: Waitlist and Free Content. There are two buttons already created: Buy Now and Official Website. The functionality of the buttons I created is identical to the Buy Now button, which only appears when we place a link within the button field. OK? The problem is when I register a new product, the old products already registered on the site have their contents completely emptied (without any data) and the following error appears:

```
CourseComponent.html:36 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined
at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (CourseComponent.html:37)
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:36043)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:35055)
at callViewAction (core.js:35421)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:35378)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:35056)
at callViewAction (core.js:35421)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:35378)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:35056)
at callViewAction (core.js:35421)
```

The URLs I added are also in the API I use.
Here is an excerpt from the button code:

```
<a href="{{course.website_link.url}}" target="_blank" class="cta-gtm"><button class="red">Site Oficial</button></a>
<a href="{{course.about_link.url}}" target="_blank" *ngIf="course.about_link.url" class="cta-gtm"><button>Comprar</button></a>
<a href="{{course.waiting_link.url}}" target="_blank" *ngIf="course.waiting_link.url" class="cta-gtm"><button>Lista De Espera</button></a>
<a href="{{course.free_link.url}}" target="_blank" *ngIf="course.free_link.url" class="cta-gtm"><button>Conteúdo grátis</button></a>

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-6 col-md-12 cta-a">
                    <div class="cta-course">
                        <a href="{{course.website_link.url}}" target="_blank" class="cta-gtm"><button class="red h-100">Site Oficial</button></a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-6 col-md-12">
                    <div class="cta-course">
                        <a href="{{course.about_link.url}}" *ngIf="course.about_link.url" target="_blank" class="cta-gtm"><button class="h-100">Comprar</button></a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-6 col-md-12">
                    <div class="cta-course">
                       <a href="{{course.waiting_link.url}}" *ngIf="course.waiting_link.url" target="_blank" class="cta-gtm"><button class="h-100">Lista de Espera</button></a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-6 col-md-12">
                    <div class="cta-course">
                        <a href="{{course.free_link.url}}" *ngIf="course.free_link.url" target="_blank" class="cta-gtm"><button class="h-100">Conteúdo Grátis</button></a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
```

As the project uses NoSQL (MongoDB) was it to accept the change or not? What can I do to fix this bug and get the old products back to work?

Comment: English please!

Comment: Breno Gomes da Silva, please always post in English as that will make it easier for a large number of people to read your post and provide answers. Or post it in http://pt.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

The error you see is because one of the objects you use in your template is `undefined`, and you're trying to access the `url` property of that undefined object.

Since you've added 2 new buttons, this will most likely mean that one or both of the new buttons' `course.xxx_link` doesn't exist. Please use `console.log` on the `course` variable to inspect its value and to see which link is missing from the object.

Comment: I used console.log in the course variable, there are two links URLs of the new buttons that are undefined. But my question is this, why this error? Since NoSQL accepts an insertion of new fields without changing the old records.

Comment: The code snippet in Angular that you posted has nothing to do with NoSQL. Angular is a client-side framework. You will have to find out how the old buttons received their `course` link data and provide the 2 new links there. 

If this is about a database issue then you haven't provided the correct information for us to help you.